# Django connection to Postgres in Docker failed

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm using macOS, building a Django app with Postgres and I want to containerise it with Docker.

I have following files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /medicin_api
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python3", "./manage.py", "runserver", "8001"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: latest
services:
  db_api:
    image: postgres:16
    restart: always
    container_name: db_api
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=api_user
      - POSTGRES_DB=medicin_patients
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Baz#Dan&Api!
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U api_user -d medicin_patients"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10

  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - .:/api_volume
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      db_api:
        condition: service_healthy

volumes:
  postgres:
```

PostgreSQL setup in django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'medicin_patients',
        'USER': 'api_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'Baz#Dan&Api!',
        'HOST': 'db_api',
        'PORT': '5433'
    }
}
```

When I run the command: `docker-compose up -d --build` I'm getting two images & containers, where:

- `db_api` container is running properly with PostgreSQL database and I can access it via CLI
- `api` container is running however it throws me below error which I cannot solve:

```
2023-12-10 12:32:25 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2023-12-10 12:32:25 Exception in thread django-main-thread:
2023-12-10 12:32:25 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-10 12:32:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
2023-12-10 12:32:25     self.connect()
2023-12-10 12:32:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2023-12-10 12:32:25     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-10 12:32:25            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-12-10 12:32:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
2023-12-10 12:32:25     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
2023-12-10 12:32:25                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-12-10 12:32:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
2023-12-10 12:32:25     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-10 12:32:25            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-12-10 12:32:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
2023-12-10 12:32:25     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
2023-12-10 12:32:25                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-12-10 12:32:25   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 745, in connect
2023-12-10 12:32:25     raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
2023-12-10 12:32:25 psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: Connection refused
2023-12-10 12:32:25     Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

What am I missing here or have wrongly setup that my Django app is not connecting with PostgreSQL?

Comment: The standard PostgreSQL port is 5432, not 5433.  You need to use that port number for connections between containers; `ports:` aren't used or considered.  The second `ports:` number also needs to be this standard port number.

Comment: @DavidMaze, when I use port 5432 i get following error: `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5432 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use`. Is this an issue which will not happen during deployment on EC2? I'm facing it on my local machine...

Comment: Since `ports:` aren't used for connections between containers, you can try just deleting that and see if that helps.  If you need to access the database from outside Docker, and host port 5432 is already in use, you can change _only the first_ `ports:` number to something else.  You'd pass that to something like a host `psql -p` option, but everything else – the second `ports:` number, port numbers for connections between containers – stays at the standard port 5432.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem you described is caused by wrong port that you exposed from the Postgresql container. As mentioned above the Postgresql operates by default on port `5432`. So, have two options:

1. Change the default port by adding a new environment variable to `db_api` container: `PGPORT: 5433`.
2. Since, the port `5432` is occupied on your host machine, you can change the mapping without changing the configuration of Posgresql instance, by changing the port mapping: `- "5433:5432"`

Comment: Thanks @Ilya, the second point worked out and solved my problem.